# Convert C struct to Java

Tags: java, c, struct

Can anyone please teach me how to convert this to Java.

```
typedef struct{
    int age;
    int dateOfBirth;
}StudentInfo;

typedef StudentInfo *StudentPtr;

typedef struct studentNode{
    StudentPtr studentPtr;
    struct studentNode *next;
}StudentNode;

typedef struct {
    StudentNode *head;
    StudentNode *tail;
}Queue;
```

Following is what I tried.

```
class StudentInfo{
int age;
int dateOfBirth;
}

class StudentNode{
StudentInfo studentPtr;
StudentNode next;
}

class Queue{
StudentNode head;
StudentNode tail
}
```

Is there another way of doing it? Without creating 2 extra classes just for that?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of StudentNode and Queue
you could use an

```
ArrayList<StudentInfo> studentList;
```

Bur read first an intro to java Collections

Comment: ArrayList has slow removal of the first element. It's - per se - not a good queue

Comment: Who will remove the first student ;-) Comparisosn showed that up to 10.000 Elements the ArrayList is faster than then LinkedList in all discpiplines, even in delete (seems that memcopy is faster than the pointer exchange)

Comment: Yeah, as far as I know ArrayList > LinkedList in almost all situations. I merely used LinkedList because that's what the OP had in the code he wanted to convert.

Answer (score 3):

You could start by joining the StudentNode and StudentInfo classes, so that you have:

```
class StudentNode {
    int age
    int dateOfBirth
    StudentNode next
}
```

Of course, that means the object that knows about student information also knows about the list, which may not be very desirable.
Alternatively, you could just use the LinkedList class:

```
LinkedList<StudentInfo> queue = new LinkedList<>();
```

That gets rid of two of them...

Comment: Thanks for your help. How do I set quueue.head in java?

Comment: LinkedList is not a queue class in and of itself. If you want to use it as a queue then you just go `queue.add(item)` and then `queue.removeFirst()` I think. Or some other combination of `.push`, `.add`, `.removeFirst`, `.removeLast` and `.pop`, I'm really not up to reasoning it out without testing. Check out the javadocs: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html **edit:** ok, actually it is a queue. `queue.offer(item)` and `queue.remove()`: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is that what you are trying to do is create a queue of StudentNodes, where each StudentNode has the properties of holding the data (StudentInfo) and a reference to the next item in the queue.

[Here's a good link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) to start off with which talks about the Queue interface in Java.

AlexWien and Jeff are talking about LinkedLists versus ArrayLists, and [there's a nice stackoverflow explanation through this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322715/when-to-use-linkedlist-over-arraylist) for you to reference more.

My recommendation is to start out with two classes: StudentQueue (which implements the Queue interface) and StudentNode (as you did in your example).  In this way you can utilize the code and concepts you know in C and apply them to Java while learning about one of Java's collections.  It will eliminate one of your two extra classes, and it's an easier way to start off than just jumping right into a List.